# How to play HD videos with ATI Radeon HD 2600 XT graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdvideo, playback

I have a Windows 7 machine equipped with ATI Radeon HD 2600 XT graphics card.
I have a LCD monitor capable to play 1080p Full HD material. I have a 3000mhz intel processor, and 4G Ram.

I am trying to play HD video, 1080p format and it doesn't work out, the picture gets freezing all the time. What shall I do?

Comment: Which player you using

Comment: I've tried Media Player Classic and VLC Player.

Comment: I had trouble getting full 1080p going on a 3870 graphics card about 8 months ago, I would expect an older card like a 2600 to struggle worse than that.  nVidia seem to have much better support for GPU based video decoding, at least on their higher cards...

Answer (score 0):

- Try installing lastest DivX codecs
- Also ffdshow latest
- Download these software which will tell you which codecs you lack on your system

> **1)** AVICodec , Go here http://www.free-codecs.com/download/AVIcodec.htm
>
> **2)** Gspot , go here to download http://www.free-codecs.com/download/GSpot.htm

Comment: Are the DivX codecs better than CoreAVC, and do they support the hardware acceleration provided by my graphics card?

Comment: I don't know if they are better than CoreAVC but it will support your graphic card

Comment: I've installed DivX, and 1080 never started, and 720 played well, but no clear sound.

Answer (score 0):

As a former owned of an ATI 2600, I feel your pain. If you are looking for a program that will use the GPU to help decode the file you are out of luck. VLC just added hardware acceleration to 1.1 and the issues that you will run into are:

1. It is somewhat buggy and crashy.
2. It only works on the the 4000 and 5000 series cards.

http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding

Your best bet is to go with Media Player Classic Home Cinema, which is included with the K-Lite Codec Package which I really fancy. It seems to work with most GPUs, new and old, assuming you have current drivers.

Check FileHippo for K-Lite, you won't regret it.

Please note that this will only use the GPU on certain files, like x264, so if you're using something else, your mileage will vary. Make sure, when installing K-Lite, you check the box for GPU acceleration, or it will be all for not.

Good luck!

---

Source: I watched the 1080p version of the Dark Knight with a HIS 2600 XT four months ago in Media Player Classic Home Cinema. Poetry in motion.